# Create a report using 2 different data sources

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008, linked-server

I need to create a report which uses 2 different datasets on different servers.

The queries run fine when run separately. But I am unable to link them.

Query1:

```
SELECT Employee.[Person Number],
       Employee.[Ethnic Origin],
       COUNT(Employee.[Person Number]) AS Staf_Count
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Employee.[Person Number],
         Employee.[Ethnic Origin]
```

Query2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT y.StYear,
                s.Student_ID,
                s.Ethnicity,
                COUNT(s.Ethnicity) AS EthCount,
                CASE s.STUD_Ethnicity
                    WHEN 31 THEN 'White - English / Welsh / Scottish / Northern Irish / British'
                    WHEN 32 THEN 'White - Irish'
                    WHEN 33 THEN 'White - Gypsy or Irish Traveller'
                    WHEN 34 THEN 'White - Any Other White background'
                    WHEN 35 THEN 'Mixed  / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Black Caribbean'
                    WHEN 36 THEN 'Mixed  / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Black African'
                    WHEN 37 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Asian'
                    WHEN 38 THEN 'Mixed  / Multiple Ethnic group - Any Other Mixed / multiple ethnic background'
                    WHEN 39 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Indian'
                    WHEN 40 THEN 'Asian/ Asian British - Pakistani'
                    WHEN 41 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Bangladeshi'
                    WHEN 42 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Chinese'
                    WHEN 43 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Any other Asian background'
                    WHEN 44 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean /  Black British - African'
                    WHEN 45 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean /  Black British - Caribbean'
                    WHEN 46 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean /  Black British - Any other Black / African / Caribbean background'
                    WHEN 47 THEN 'Other ethnic group - Arab'
                    WHEN 98 THEN 'Any Other'
                    WHEN 99 THEN 'Not provided'
                END AS Ethnicity
FROM dbo.STUDstudent s
LEFT JOIN dbo.GNICodes g ON s.Ethnicity = g.GNIC_Code
INNER JOIN dbo.STYRstudentYR y ON s.Student_ID = y.Student_ID
WHERE STYR_Year = @Year
GROUP BY s.Student_ID,
         s.Ethnicity
```

O/P: Should look like below:

[image: Ethnicity Table]

I have checked and 2nd database is listed as  linked server under first one.

Report design looks below:

[image: Report_Design]

Created a View combining both datasets:

```
CREATE VIEW Staff_Student_Ethnicity
AS
        SELECT  DISTINCT 
    [Ethnic Origin] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI AS Ethnicity, 
    COUNT([Person Number]) AS Staf_Count
    FROM  Employee.[Monitoring with Organisation As At Evaluation Date]
    GROUP BY  [Ethnic Origin]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT 
    Ethnicity COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI , 
    COUNT(STUD_Ethnicity) AS StudCount
    FROM SQL10.NG.[dbo].[Student_Ethnicity]
    GROUP BY Ethnicity
```

But after executing the View, I just see Ethnicity and Staf_Count fields and StudCount is missing..Please let me know where am I going wrong...

Comment: Your first aggregation query doesn't make sense, it's trying to count the number of `[person number]s` per `[person number]`.

Comment: What error are you getting when you execute these queries?

Comment: @Chris Pickford - I am trying to count No of persons per ethnic group

Comment: @scsimon: Please see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the error and screen shot in your example Aruna. I'm sure someone with more SSRS knowledge will explain why aggregated columns must originate from the same source as your category axis identifier, I just know this is the case in many visual platforms such as Spotfire and Tableau and seems to be the case here. However, there's a work around.

Instead of bringing in TWO separate data sources from separate data elements, handle the relations on the server side. Since your servers are already linked, create a `STORED PROCEDURE` on one of the servers which combines both of the data tables. You can much easier control the relation of the data and the expected results. Then, use this as your data source for your SSRS report.

```
CREATE VIEW Staff_Student_Ethnicity
AS
    SELECT  DISTINCT 
    [Ethnic Origin] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI AS Ethnicity, 
    COUNT([Person Number]) AS Staf_Count,
    NULL as StudCount
    FROM  Employee.[Monitoring with Organisation As At Evaluation Date]
    GROUP BY  [Ethnic Origin]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT 
    Ethnicity COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI , 
    NULL as Staf_Count,
    COUNT(STUD_Ethnicity) AS StudCount
    FROM SQL10.NG.[dbo].[Student_Ethnicity]
    GROUP BY Ethnicity
```

**EDIT FOR DRILL DOWN**

If you want to have the details of your aggregations to build a layered report in SSRS, then you are going to have to bring in those details from your query. Therefore, you might as well do the aggregations in SSRS for your counts and not have two queries. A simple procedure as the one below should combine your data for you. Then, you can bring this into SSRS and aggregate the columns as you want. I put in a `PersonType` field for you to use in your `IF` statements in SSRS. i.e. `IF([PersonType] = 'Student' then Count([PersonNumber])) as [StudentCount]`. I know this syntax isn't accurate for SSRS, but I am just giving an example of the logic.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_staff_student_sthnicity()
AS
    SELECT  DISTINCT 
    [Ethnic Origin] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI AS Ethnicity, 
    [Person Number] AS PersonNumber,
    'Staff' as PersonType
    FROM  Employee.[Monitoring with Organisation As At Evaluation Date]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT 
    Ethnicity COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI, 
    Student_ID AS PersonNumber
    'Student' as PersonType
    FROM SQL10.NG.[dbo].[Student_Ethnicity]
```

Then, you can enable a user to click on the `StudentCount` or `EmployeeCount` fields and see the students / employees that are associated with this aggregation. Steps on how to do this is subject to a new question post on StackOverflow after research though.

Comment: Please see above after I created view joining both datasets...I only see fields from first dataset in the View results ....And I see all counts in a single table...

Comment: In your union all, you will only have two columns and it will take the name of the first one you alias. Thus, the `StudCount` will be under the `Staf_Count` column.

Test with this

`select 
 1 as One,
 2 as Two

union all

select
 1 as One,
 3 as Three`

Comment: how can I get separately?

Comment: i added your code to my answer, with the NULL so you will separate them

Comment: any idea if drill down is possible in this case below staff/student counts?

Comment: in what aspects? Can you elaborate?

Comment: In order to do that you will have to NOT aggregate the data in SSMS. Are you using this data in something like SSRS or a visualization BI tool like Spitfire?

Comment: I edit my post to help you out. If the counts are off, it's likely to do with how you are limiting the data from the two queries on your side. In the `procedure` above, you can add any parameters you want, like @Date, and filter the datasets for both queries on it.

Comment: Created store dproc as you have suggested and while execution get this error: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Staff and Student Ethnicity, Line 4
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '702179V     ' to data type int. Its for Student_ID field

Comment: That means your student_id aren't all it but your person numbers are. Just cast the person number to a varchar(16) or how ever large you need.

Comment: =IIF(Fields!PersonType.Value="Student",Sum(Fields!StudCount.Value, "Student"), Sum(Fields!StaffCount.Value, "Staff")) used this expression for calculating counts but I get same count for all the columns...

Comment: I'm not sure how you are using StudCount with the procedure, since it is not in the procedure and isn't aggregated. The procedure is detailed rows, so you'll have to count the Student ID or Person Number

Comment: ok I am calculating the counts in the datasets and including a filter on tablix for PersonType = Student and PersonType = Staff but only one count and % shows up.but not both :(

Comment: I'd have to see your RDL to really help with that. Sorry

Comment: For now I am importing data from Excel to SQL Table and using it as source for my report....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Lookup function to get the number of students from the second dataset. In this case, Ethnicity would be your key. So the expression would be:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Ethnic_Origin.Value, Fields!Ethnicity.Value, Fields!EthCount.Value, "StudentEthnicity")
```

Resource: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx

Comment: Steven: tried this but getting error: The value expression for textrun has an incorrect number of parameters for the function Lookup

Comment: @ArunaRaghunam It takes 4 parameters, but they do have to be the correct type and in the correct order.